# Error: "The item with the specified name wasn't found."

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've been looking for this problem, but cannot find a solution that works for me.

I've made option buttons through the UI of word 2013 , and gave them a specified name in their properties ( "knop11" )

```
ThisDocument.Shapes("knop11").Visible = False
```

The above line is what I try to use to hide my option button when pressing a command button.
After making a new option button ( with default name "OptionButton1 ) it still doesn't work if I apply it to that button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the type of control you are inserting, if you are using a ActiveX option button, it is not included within the shapes, but it will be created as an independent object. In such case you just have to use its functions directly.
However there is no 'visibility' property within option buttons, you might use a harsh work around like changing the buttons size or its forecolor. Something like:

```
If knop11.Height > 1 Then
    knop11.Height = 1
Else
    knop11.Height = 20
End If
```

Just as a quick tip, when you make the UI, the controls that are included within the shapes of the document are the ContentControls, and normally you fill the TAG property to look for them later. You might as well use the check box content control, and programming the option behaviour within your macros.